How to pull all the data on the "right" of a column with certain value in the header
I am trying to pull out certain columns of information from a autogenerated report for further analysis. I will need to only pull certain columns based on the header values.
Here is the link to the sheet with the sample data and the formula tab where i am working on.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S9trBPD-si2wK_LjcUTzB7GTQB99FXgWPQdbn4jNNGY/edit?usp=sharing
Report doesnt always follow the same order and to make things worse for certain  columns, the header value also changes. Example : in "Data" tab, from coulmns C  onwards, the values keep changing based on which quarter the report is run on.

I have already managed to pull the first column by using the below formula, as the column header is always fixed for this. (Have applied it in A1 in "Formula" tab)
=ifna(index(Data!$A$1:$H, 0, match("Building",Data!1:1,0)), "-")
But for the next part i need to pull all data from the column thats mentioned as "Qtr End", D1 in this example, as well as any data thats on the right of that column as well. in other words, everything from column D to H from the Data tab.
I am partially able to pull just the "Qtr End" column by modifing the same formula as shown below.
=ifna(index(Data!$A$1:$H, 0, match("*Qtr*",Data!1:1,0)), "-")
But how can i modify the formula to also pull all the columns right of this as well?
Thanks in advance for the help!!
Ramya

You can try:
={A:A,filter(A:H,sequence(1,columns(A:H))>=xlookup("*Qtr*",A1:H1,column(A1:H1),,2))}

The xlookup returns the number of the column containing 'Qtr' and by evaluating using >= against a sequence of all the column numbers we generate a TRUE/FALSE array where all columns >= the 'Qtr' column are TRUE. We then simply filter the whole table by this array and stack the result alongside the 'Building' column.

Thanks a lot!! the formula works!! :)

The Formula really worked like a charm, even when i tweaked it a little to match my complicated real table!! Thanks again The God of Biscuits!!!

Is it possible to include a fliter in this formula to exclude the rows which have a sum value of zero for the whole row. Example Row 2, in which Building A has zero value for all the quarters.
